# How do I model time to an event with online data?

Tags: time-series, survival, online-algorithms

I am looking at streaming data (i.e. online model), and looking for a specific discrete event. I want to stochastically model the time until this even happens, or if easier, say, model the probability that it happens within the next 30 seconds. What is a simple, practical way to tackle this problem? What kind of technique can I use, and how can I train the model and backtest it?

Note that the training is happening offline on historical data, and then the model is applied online, on live, streaming data.

Answer (score 3):

To add some detail the survival function is the probability that an event occurs by time t as a function of t.  Given data on time to event even in the case where some data are right censored (i.e. analysis is to be done before each case has an event).  So with right censoring there are some case where we know only that for a specific time t$_0$ no even thas occurred.  Given this kind of data there are parametric(e.g. exponential, Weibull models), semiparametric (e.g. Cox proportional hazards model) and nonparametric methods (e.g. the Kaplan-Meier product limit estimator) for estimating the survival function.

Answer (score 0):

Survival analysis...see cox models or KM models.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Reeza. I wonder if you'd be willing to flesh out this answer somewhat to be more helpful to the OP & future readers of this Q. Can you say more about what survival analyses are, & why they're a good approach to this situation (some links or pointers to more info might help, too).